# How to access self.function from global class scope

Tags: python, django

How to pass `Foo.finished` callback into `doSmthAsync`. Is it possible somehow to access self while `doSmthAsync(callback=self.finished)` definition.

```
import doSmthAsync from library

class Foo:
    doJob = doSmthAsync(callback=self.finished)

    def finished():
        pass
```

For those who will suggest to reconstruct code: I know a lot of tricks how to workaround of it. But question is about accessibility of `self` while `doSmthAsync(callback=self.finished)` definition.

Comment: I'm confused. Do you want to access the `Foo()` object from the callback? A [**Minimal**, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be useful here.

Comment: why not pass ``self`` as a parameter to ``doSmthAsync``? Then you can access ``self`` and all it's attributes and methods.

Comment: @Alex I wont to pass `self.finished` to `doSmthAsync` ext function.

Comment: @Mike Scotty but `self` is unavailable at this moment (the moment when I try to use it)

Comment: maybe do this in `__init__` instead of at the class level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`self` is nothing magical, it's just a naming convention for [the first argument to instance methods](https://wiki.python.org/moin/FromFunctionToMethod), which is expected to be a reference to the current instance (the one one which the method was called). IOW it's an ordinary function argument - technically a local variable.

FWIW, within a `class` statement block, the class object itself doesn't even exist yet - it's only created after the `class` statement has been executed -, so there's no way to reference the class from within the class statement. But you don't actually need to, you can directly access the `finished` function (yes I said "function", because at this point it's a plain function, cf the above link) from within the class statement block - at least once the function has been defined:

```
class Foo(object):

    def finished(self):
        pass

    print("finished : {}".format(finished)
```

I don't know what `doSmthAsync` is supposed to do so it's impossible to post a proper pythonic solution to your problem, but it can certainly be solved with a property or a custom descriptor - or even a plain method FWIW.

Comment: I've accepted your answer, but what mean words: IOW, FWIW, cf?

Comment: "in other words", "for what it's worth", "see also"